# $4$ balls are randomly distributed into $3$ cells. What is the probability that there is a cell that contains exactly $2$ balls?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$4$ balls are randomly distributed into $3$ cells ($3^4=81$ possibilities of equal probability).

What is the probability that there is a cell that contains exactly $2$ balls?

The correct answer is: $\frac{2}{3}$, but i know don't where was i mistaken.

Here was my idea:

Let's define: $\forall _{i=1,2,3}:A_i$ = The event that cell #$i$ contains exactly $2$ balls.

Then, according to the *Inclusion–exclusion principle*, the answer should be:

$P_{solution} = P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-P(A_1\cap A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_3)-P(A_2\cap A_3)+P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3)$

Where:
$$
\forall _{i=1,2,3}: \quad P(A_i)=\frac{{4 \choose 2}*2^2}{3^4}=\frac{8}{27}
$$
$$
\forall_{i \neq j}: \quad P(A_i \cap A_j)= \frac{{4 \choose 2}*2}{3^4}=\frac{4}{27}
$$
$$
P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3)=0
$$

and so:

$$P_{solution}=3*\frac{8}{27}-3*\frac{4}{27} = \frac{4}{9}$$

I can see that IF my calculation of $P(A_i \cap A_j)$ was $\frac{{4 \choose 2}}{3^4}$ (without multiplying by $2$), then that would be correct, but i can't seem not to wonder why. I have to multiply by $2$. Suppose we look at cell #1 and cell #2: I need to choose $2$ balls out of $4$, that's $4 \choose 2$. Let's say i chose the the balls $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$, then i must decide which cell will get the $\{1,3\}$ set and which will the $\{2,4\}$. That's $2$ options, so we multiply by $2$.

Any idea? Where was i mistaken? Can you show me your solutions?

Comment: There are 81 possible configurations. I recommend enumerating each of them. This is an easy way to verify your math for Inclusion/Exclusion, as well. You find that your suspicion of where you were incorrect is exactly where you were incorrect.

Comment: @SlipEternal explicitly brute force enumerating a situation with more than 20 outcomes seems like a bad idea.  Yes, it can prove one way or another and is simple to understand from a theoretical standpoint, but too many cases and they blur together on the paper.  It can be difficult to manually count and it can be difficult to be sure each case was written once and only once without being extremely careful.  The whole point of a course in combinatorics is to learn how to count *without* having to resort to such measures.

Comment: @JMoravitz Enumerating them by hand is certainly problematic, but simple programs like Excel and Google Sheets allow you to enumerate problems with many outcomes carefully and accurately without the "extreme care" you mention. Consider a sheet with the formulas: $$\begin{array}{c|l}A1 & \text{=MOD(ROW()-1,3)} \\ B1 & \text{=MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/3),3)} \\ C1 & \text{=MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/9),3)} \\ D1 & \text{=MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/27),3)}\end{array}$$ Copy that row to the next 80 rows, and you have successfully enumerated all outcomes.

Comment: @SlipEternal While you might have access to such technology in real life, and admittedly there are some problems too difficult to solve by pen-and-paper methods that this would be helpful for, you won't be able to use this in a testing environment and the specific problem posed by the OP here is simple enough that with practice one can solve it in their head with mental arithmetic.  Setting up a spreadsheet to brute force this is overkill, unnecessary, and frankly bad advice.  Again, the whole point of a course like the one OP is in is to learn how to *avoid* doing precisely that.

Comment: @JMoravitz My experience teaching and tutoring combinatorics, the students who spent the time understanding the brute force methods gained a much better understanding of combinatorial techniques. Rather than memorizing methods, they were able to put the methods together with what they actually mean. They could see the methods they used at work. So, while it may be overkill, unnecessary, and frankly bad advice for you, it has worked for many of my students. In the end, different people learn differently, and stifling advice that does not work for you is typically bad form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the approach you take, it should be,

$P =  \displaystyle 3 \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{2^2}{3^4} - 3 \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^4}$

Please note that $ \displaystyle P(A_i \cap A_j) = {4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^4}$

Explanation: Once you choose two of the three cells for $2$ balls each, there are ${4 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing balls for the first of the selected two cells and the remaining two go to the second cell. In other words, they are already ordered and you should not multiply by $2$.

However for this question, instead of Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, you can choose direct counting too as there are only two cases.

Comment: ohh now i see! So i must see the selected cells as ordered. Actually, i knew those kind of things all the time, but for some reason that confused me this time.

When we equaly distribute a deck of cards to $4$ players, we have: ${52 \choose 13}{39 \choose 13}{26 \choose 13}{13 \choose 13}=\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$ ways of doing that. We don't multiply by $4$.

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ryden exactly! you have the right example in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing $\{1,3\}$ and bin $2$ is equivalent to choosing $\{2,4\}$ and choosing bin $1$.

Perhaps a cleaner way of finding numerator for $\Pr(A_1\cap A_2)$ is by treating ball1 as special.  Choose which bin ball1 goes into: $2$ choices.  Choose which other ball goes with ball1: $3$ choices.  The remaining balls go into the other bin.  This gives a numerator of $2\times 3 = 6$ as opposed to your $12$ you had in your attempt.

For an alternate approach to verify the answer of $\frac{2}{3}$, let us see which outcomes were "bad."  By pigeonhole principle every arrangement will have at least one bin with at least two balls in it.  We see then that the only bad outcomes are those where we have a bin with exactly three balls in it or a bin with exactly four.

For exactly three, pick which ball was not a part of the three.  Pick which bin it goes into.  Then, pick which bin the three go into.  For exactly four, pick which bin they all go into.  $\frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{3^4}+\frac{3}{3^4} = \frac{1}{3}$ and so the probability we were originally after is $1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: of that's a nice way of proving that.. very useful! thank you!